# Is the following code valid?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

Well let me explain the code first:

First the user enters the id, the jquery checks the database for the id..if the id exists it fetches the results and displays in the remaining form boxes, if not it displays no id with some styling.

here is the code:

Javascript and html

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button1").click(function()
{
//remove all the class add the messagebox classes and start fading

$("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
    //checks if the id exists
    $.post("script_3.php",{ id:$('#id').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
    {
        if(data=='yes')//correct id detail
        {
            $$("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
            {
                $(this).html('Logging in.....').addClass('messageboxok').fadeTo(900,1,
                function()
                {
                  $.post('script_1.php', { id: $('input[name="id"]', '#myForm').val()   

 },  
                  function(json) { 
                  $("input[name='title']").val(json.title);
                  $("input[name='name']").val(json.rno);
                     }, "json"); 
                     });

        });
      } 

      else 
      {
          $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
          { 
          //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
          $(this).html('NO ID...').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
        });        
      }

    });
     return false; //not to post the  form physically
});
```

Html side:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
}
.top {
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.buttondiv {
margin-top: 10px;
}
.messagebox{
position:absolute;
width:100px;
margin-left:30px;
border:1px solid #c93;
background:#ffc;
padding:3px;
}
.messageboxok{
position:absolute;
width:auto;
margin-left:30px;
border:1px solid #349534;
background:#C9FFCA;
padding:3px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#008000;

}
.messageboxerror{
 position:absolute;
width:auto;
margin-left:30px;
border:1px solid #CC0000;
background:#F7CBCA;
padding:3px;
font-weight:bold;
color:#CC0000;
}

</style>

<body>

<form id="myForm" method="post">
id: <input type="text" name="id"/>
<div id="hidden" style="display: none;">
<p>Title:<input type="text" name="title"/></p>
<p>Name:<input type="text" name="rno"/>
</div>
<br/> 
<input type="button" id="button1" value ="Get Info"        
onclick="document.getElementById('hidden').style.display = '';"/> 
<span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
</form>
<div id="age"></div>
</body>
```

script_3.php

```
 <?php
  //connect to DB removed
 $id= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

$sql="SELECT id FROM parentid WHERE id='".$id."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
echo "yes";
    //now set the session from here if needed
    $_SESSION['u_id']=$id; 
 }
 else
 echo "no"; //Invalid Login
 ?>
```

Well the problem i have is its not going to script_1.php part and it is always displaying no id error even if i enter the correct id.

I there any syntax error in the code??

plzz let me know if u have ant questions.

Comment: This is a lot of code to debug just on sight - you should start debugging it yourself, you have the environment to test it in. The first step is to look whether `$id` is transferred at all, e.g. using `print_r($_POST);` in script_1.php

Comment: Create a simplified version of the code. Run it. Simplify it further. Run it. Simplify it further. Run it. Repeat until the error stop happening. Add the complexity back in. Find out exactly where the error happens. Then either [1] fix it or [2] post the resulting code to StackOverflow, explaining exactly where the error seems to happen. -1.

Comment: @pekka: i know its to much of a code ...but if u observe it ..its not submitting the info rather its getting the info..i think it would not be possible to use print_r($_POST)..

Comment: @John: The more code you submit, the less people are likely to read it. Just like Chris suggested, you need to create a reduction of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem may be

```
$('#id').val()
```

There is no element with the `id='id'`

Comment: Could be the problem, there's a form element with `name='id'`, and IE <=7 will return that element if you call document.getElementById('id'). This code may have been written for IE. Try changing the `name='id'` to `id='id'` See http://jsfiddle.net/nBmVX/ using IE <=7

Answer (score 0):

You may open firebug in firefox browser or inspect element in google chrome to see if there is a JavaScript error or to view the server response from the calling of the **script_3** ,Also use the     'var_dump'.   Or the print_r functions to see if the parameters from the JavaScript reach the server correctly or they don't

Answer (score 0):

1/

From what I can see on this line:

> < p>Name:< input type="text" name="rno"/>

taken from HTML side you havent closed the `<p>` tag to close it put `</p>`.

2/

on the script_3

> else  echo "no";

you forgot the brackets. needs to be:

> else {
>
> echo "no";}

3/

on script_1

you have:

> ?php

it needs to be:

> < ?php

Hope this helps