# Is there any error in the code?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have the following code in jquery, what it does is when the user submits (button1) it goes script_1.php .In script_1.php file it returns "yes" if its true or false when it is not.
My problem is even if the value submitted by script_1.php is 'yes' it is going to else part of the code instead of going to if part(if(data=='yes')).

Is there any problem with the code??

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button1").click(function()
{
$("#msgbox").removeClass().addClass('messagebox').text('Validating....').fadeIn(1000);
    //checks if the id exists
    $.post("script_3.php",{ id:$('#id').val(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
    {
        if(data=='yes')//correct id detail
        {
      //some other code
        }
 else 
      {
          $("#msgbox").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
          { 
          //add message and change the class of the box and start fading
          $(this).html('NO ID...').addClass('messageboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
        });        
      }

    });
```

script_3.php

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM parentid WHERE id='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
echo "yes";

}
```

Note: i have checked the syntax errors like closing,opening brackets or such errors everything is fine.I think there might me some error in jquery part.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the PHP script actually displays "yes" (with Firebug or similar)?

Comment: As already said in your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098562/is-the-following-code-valid), **start debugging your code.** Walk through it step by step and find at which point the values stop being what you want them to be. Use `alert()` or `console.log()` to output variable values, and a tool like Firebug to look at Ajax requests and what actually gets sent. Use `print_r()` to output things on PHP end. Have the jQuery manual handy. When you find the point at which things start to go wrong, come back to Stack Overflow with a specific question about *that.*

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug, Fiddler, etc.. to verify what is being returned by your `$.post` call?

Comment: yes i have checked with php script and it displays yes..

Comment: And where exactly do you fetch the value for $id in script_3.php from before you use it in the query? register_globals is a thing of the past. And to debug your javascript I suggest you use Firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a javascript debugger of some sort?  Many browsers are starting to include them these days, but I prefer firebug for firefox above them all.

http://getfirebug.com/

With firebug you can set breakpoints in your javascript and see what is going on at every moment in your code.